# Rolling back database changes

Tags: database, frameworks, workflow, rollback, business-process-management

I  work in team which uses Work flow management tool. I was presented with a challenge where  the user should be able to roll back the changes made anytime during the flow to a certain point in the past. Surely the toll can handle it but the additional database calls that may have made during these activities have to be manually rolled back.

the challenge is that there are multiple parallel paths and there different permutations of external database calls. So is there a frame work or a way to keep track of these DB calls and rollback them?.

thank you,
Justin

Comment: If you have a flow A which changes a record and flow B might change that same record, and whoever started flow A wants to roll back... I'd say your screwed.  And god forbid if during the processing of flow A one or more other flows (C,D,E..) were kicked off and one of those were later rolled back...  Sounds like a mess.  You might want to talk to the project sponsors on that one.

Comment: Are you talking schema changes independently of the data? Or Data Changes? Or both?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, i dont think so.

In **Entity Framework** for example you have `TRANSACTIONS` and `ROLLBACK` function but this `ROLLBACK` only changes in this `TRANSACTION` from begining of this start (`START TRANSACTION` - *SQL Statement*)

Then you will must have in multiple parallel paths start a `TRANSACTION` and take a decision of `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` changes. But before `COMMIT` other parallel instances will not see changes maded in other `TRANSACTIONS` who will not `COMMITED` yet.

I think, you must do some **refactorization** on your *application/database*, but this is only offtopic hint.

Comment: @Aren B . I am talking only about data changes.

Answer (score 0):

Are these changes committed to the database already at an intermediate state?  That's going to be problematic.  Since other users may have started actions based on committed data.

I have seen systems which support n-level undo prior to commit (CSLA does this), but this is at the object model level in memory.

You would not hold a database transaction open indefinitely waiting for user action.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to rollback or do you need the data to be in a certain state?  I ask since if the latter is the case, then it is a matter or setting your record back to values that you had prior to Workflow step X.

There is a design pattern called the [Momento Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) that takes a snapshot of your objects at key intervals and persists that data in addition to the "current" data in your database.  This type transaction could be stored as a serialization of your objects and recorded and hence you would need to create a history table for every table that you currently have.

The trick will be to restore your objects from the Memento transactions, the save the data back to you standard tables.